# Building a slim war in Grails 3.1.7

Tags: grails, gradle, war

I want to assemble a war file w/o any jar files (I copied them to my `/opt/tomcat8/lib` dir already).

I read about `-nojars` [options](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/05/create-much-smaller-grails-war-file.html), but it's not available for Grails 3.1.7.

Then I tried customizing my `build.gradle`:

```
war{
  rootSpec.exclude "**/*.jar"
}
```

and the resulting war indeed became very small ~1 MB. Although when I deploy it into a tomcat and call the `http://host:8080/`, I'm getting

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1229)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1029)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)

What's the proper way to build the slim war's?

SIDE NOTE:

The application contains only of a couple of domain classes and scaffolded controllers. No views were modified after `grails create-app`

Comment: did you try this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24831624/4769188 ? This method described here: https://srinatha.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/reducing-grails-deployment-size/

Comment: basically this is exactly what I did so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First in your `build.gradle` you have to change scope of all `compile` dependencies to `provided`. For some reason `runtime` dependencies must be kept for Grails to work (i don't have explanation for that yet).

For example `compile "org.grails:grails-core"` will be changed to `provided "org.grails:grails-core"`

This will stop gradle to package libs to `WEB-INF/lib`, but it will now create new folder `WEB-INF/lib-provided` with all dependencies. These libs should not be visible to 'external' application server, but are required for archive (in this case war) execution. This is done by `bootRepackage` task.

You can disable `bootRepackage` task by adding this command to your `build.gradle`:

```
bootRepackage.enabled = false
```

Now your `war` task should create archive without any jars.

Comment: please elaborate on `set scope of all dependencies to provided`

Comment: I've modified my answer for clarification

Comment: should I put `bootRepackage.enabled = false` to some specific task, or simply to the root?

Comment: so, I tried the `provided` trick, and got a war file of ~ 1 MB (with all jars stripped, as in my original attempt). Upon calling the index, I'm getting `ERROR org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/] due t
o exception [Could not resolve view with name '/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet']`

Comment: it looks like you have to keep `runtime` dependencies in war and only `compile` can be removed. For your project it should be only `asset-pipeline` and `h2`, so still significant war size reduction.

Comment: I left `runtime 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2'` (I don't use `h2`) and changed `compile` to `provided`. I'm still getting the exception though...

Comment: now I've noticed, that my grails project is not 3.1.7 but 3.1.4 (i have 3.1.7 installed but 3.1.4 was set as default). 3.1.4 works fine, but when i now created 3.1.7 I'm getting same exception. Looks like there could be a bug in new version of asset plugin

Comment: that's a nice hint! I'll try it out

Comment: switching back to 3.1.4 and using `provided` or `rootSpec.exclude "**/*.jar"` did help

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up, I created an [issue](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10090), and as Graeme couldn't reproduce the behavior, the ticket was closed. Although for me it still didn't work.

So I came up with a simple workaround, which is not that elegant as my original wish, but is very straight-forward:

1. unzip the slim .war-file into ~/ROOT/
2. copy all Grails 3.1.11 + plugins dependency jars into ~/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib

Note: `sym-link` DID NOT work...

3. move the ~/ROOT folder to /opt/tomcat/webapps

Thus, the war file I create on my build-machine and send over to prod remains thin